# About the equivalence relation $f\sim f' \iff f-f'=2g$ on $F^{ab}(A)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a couple of exercises, P. Aluffi utilizes the following equivalence relation on the free abelian group $F=F^{ab}(A)$:
$$f\sim f'\quad\iff\quad f-f'=2g\:\:\:\text{ for some }g\in F.$$
Since this appears quite frequently in the exercises, I would like to know if it is of any importance in algebra or in some other field.

Also, I know that
$$\frac{F}{\sim}=\frac{F}{2F}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus A}}{2\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus A}}$$
and I think that this is also equal to
$$\left(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}\right)^{\oplus A}$$
but I'm not sure about how I could prove it. I tried to use some universal properties but it didn't worked very well. How could I do it?

Comment: If you define $\phi : F \to (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z})^{\oplus A}$ by $(\phi(f))_a = f(a) \text{ mod } 2$ for every $a \in A$, isn't $\phi$ surjective and having as its kernel $2F$ ?

Comment: @Junkyards Just to be sure, in this case you are viewing $F$ as the set of funcions $A\to\mathbb{Z}$ which are non-zero for only a finite number of the $a\in A$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in \Bbb Z^{\oplus A}$, then we can write $f = \sum_{a \in A}n_a[a]$ for integers $n_a \in \Bbb Z$, with $[a]$ denoting the basis element corresponding to $a \in A$. Denote by $\bar n \in \Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z$ the image of $n$ under the obvious quotient map.

Let us define the morphism
$$
\varphi : \Bbb Z^{\oplus A} \to (\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z)^{\oplus A},\; \sum_{a \in A} n_a[a] \mapsto \sum_{a \in A} \bar{n}_a[a].
$$

This map is clearly a surjective abelian group morphism. Now we find its kernel. If $f \in \ker \varphi$ then $f = \sum_{a \in A} n_a [a]$ with $2 | n_a$ for all $a \in A$. Then it is clear that $f \in 2 \Bbb Z^{\oplus A}$. Conversely if $f \in 2\Bbb Z^{\oplus A}$ then it is an easy check that $\varphi(f) = 0$. So $\ker \varphi = 2\Bbb Z^{\oplus A}$.

Therefore by the first isomorphism theorem
$$
\Bbb Z^{\oplus A}/ \ker \varphi = \Bbb Z^{\oplus A} / 2\Bbb Z^{\oplus A} \simeq (\Bbb Z / 2\Bbb Z)^{\oplus A}.
$$